# Forum db structure : Postcount separated?

Tags: database-design

I'm building a small forum for my website. the forum will potentially be heavily accessed and I just can't seem to get a peace of mind about the structure. I now have separate tables for counters like ForumThreadCount and ForumThreadPostCount. This gives a little bit overhead cause I need to query them separately and it's not as maintainable as putting these values in de default Forum table.

I would really like to place them in the default Forum table though which is much easier to maintain and query but I'm afraid that updating the forum table directly and (possibly) many times a minute is not really safe/best practice.

Have any of you guys been trough similair scenarios and what's your thoughts about the two methods?

Thank you for your time.

Kind regards,
Mark

Comment: Can you clarify what's in ForumThreadCount. Also you might want to include the back end you're using

Comment: What about using views for this kind of statistics?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the basic operations that will occur with what you want to do.

Any new thread involves an insert with the thread data (user, time, subject, etc.) and the counter initialized at "1" for the initial post itself (or zero if you only want to count replies).  For just that operation, keeping the counter in the same table is the simplest thing to do.

But when a new message is posted in the thread, you have two operations: writing the message data (again user, time, subject etc) plus updating the counter.   This is two writes no matter how you slice it, one to write the reply, one to update the counter.  So splitting threadCounts out from threads gives a complication without a real payoff.  So keep the reply count in the threads table.

For the overall thread count, one solution is to make a table of threads per day.  When a new thread is created, update the counter for the day.  Every month, or every two weeks, or even every three days, roll up the counts for that period and collapse them to a single row.  This way, you can do a SELECT SUM(threadCount) out of this table and you are only hitting at any time 10-14 rows, which is chickenfeed, the server won't even notice you are doing it.